# how to put a security image in php?

Tags: php, security, image

how to put a security image in php?
I wanne put it in a form, and check it on submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a solution that you can host on your own server, you can try:
http://www.phpcaptcha.org/

Although I'd recommend reCAPTCHA:
http://www.google.com/recaptcha

It fights spam and helps read books :)

Comment: Too bad the "books" reCAPTCHA is used on are mostly partial samples of obscure/low-sales books that no one wants. So instead of contributing to a noble cause (e.g. digitizing all books and making them easily accessible to everyone on the internet), you're really just helping give publishers (the very ones that ruined Google Book Search) free manual labor for their online marketing.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha), it's easy to integrate and works well.